# Selenium:How to return to the previous page after accept the alert popup？

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

I use selenium (python) for the test page.
The test process is:

1. Initially, I have a page A, and the second page B pops up by clicking a link on page A.
2. When I submitted the form on page B, an alert popup came out (only the OK button).
3. When the pop-up window is accepted, page B is automatically closed. At this time, there is only page A in the browser, and I can see it.

The question is, after page B closed, how do I get control of page A?

My code is roughly as follows：

A_handle = dr.current_window_handle #Initially operate on page A

...After accepting the popup on page B...

**dr.switch_to_window(A_handle) #This line gives an error---no such window: target window already closed**

I am very confused, does anyone have a solution？

Answer (score 1):

While one page A (so before opening page B) do:

```
main_window = dr.current_window_handle
```

To switch driver control to page B do:

```
dr.switch_to.window(dr.window_handles[1])
```

After closing page B do:

```
dr.switch_to.window(main_window)
```

You should now be back on page A.